# TypeScript Sequelize: Error when trying to include related models in a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

I have just started learning NodeJs and I have created my first project in NodeJs and now I am trying to migrate it into Typescript, But I just can't remove this error. can someone help me fix it ?

This is my group.service.ts file.

```
import { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import GroupMembers from '../models/groupmember.model';
// Import Sequelize instance (assuming it's defined in a different file)
import { sequelize } from '../models'; // Adjust the import path to match your project structure
import Groups from '../models/group.model';
class Group extends Model {
  public id!: number;
  public group_Name!: string;
}

Group.init(
  {
    group_Name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, // Adjust the data type as needed
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Groups',
  }
);

class GroupMember extends Model {
  public id!: number;
  public user_id!: number;
  public group_id!: number;
}

GroupMember.init(
  {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    group_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'GroupMembers',
  }
);

// Function to create a new group
const createGroup = async (group_Name: string, creator_id: number): Promise<Groups> => {
  try {
    const group = await Groups.create({
      creator_id,
      group_Name,
    });
    return group;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in Creating a group', error);
    throw new Error('Error in creating a group');
  }
};

// Function to get all the groups a user is part of, including private chats
const getUsersGroups = async (user_id: number): Promise<any[]> => {
  try {
    const userGroups = await GroupMembers.findAll({
      where: { user_id },
      include: [{ model: Groups }],
    });
    console.log("checking grouos", userGroups);
    return userGroups.map((entry) => entry.getDataValue('groups'));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in getting groups of the user', error);
    throw new Error('Error in getting groups of the user');
  }
};

// Function to delete a group along with its associated messages
const deleteGroupWithMessages = async (group_id: number): Promise<{ message: string }> => {
  try {
    const deleteGroup = await Groups.destroy({
      where: { id: group_id },
    });

    if (!deleteGroup) {
      throw new Error('Group not found');
    }

    return { message: 'Group and associated messages deleted successfully' };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in deleting group and group messages', error);
    throw new Error('Error in deleting group and group messages');
  }
};

export { createGroup, getUsersGroups, deleteGroupWithMessages };
```

and these are the problems I am getting

Argument of type '"groups"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof GroupMembersModelAttributes'.

Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions | undefined'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'WhereOptions'.

Answer (score 1):

first we changed this because TypeScript can't find attribute groups. To fix this, you can take advantage of the GroupMembers type definitions and use its attributes instead of the groups strings.

```
return userGroups.map((entry) => entry.Groups);
```

and

```
const userGroups = await GroupMembers.findAll({
  where: { user_id },
  include: [{ model: Groups, as: 'Groups' }],
});
```